# adding for each clause into variable

Tags: php

I have the following variable $prod_list_contents which is a mix of html and php METHODS to display the products from my database:

```
 $prod_list_contents .= '<div style="width:100%;">';
    $prod_list_contents .= '';

    while ($listing = tep_db_fetch_array($listing_query)) {
      $rows++;

            $prod_list_contents .= '
        <div class="cat_prod_box">
            <div class="image">
                <div class="cat_image_table">
                        <a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_PRODUCT_INFO, ($cPath ? 'cPath=' . $cPath . '&' : '') . 'products_id=' . $listing['products_id']) . '">' . tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES_CAT . $listing['products_image'], $listing['products_name'], 255, 340, 'class="cat_image_round"') . '
                            <div class="hidden_thing">Click to View</div>
                        </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cat_product_info" >';

            $prod_list_contents .= '<div class="span_style_num">Style: '. $listing['products_model'] . '</div>';

            $prod_list_contents .= '<div class="span_colors">Colors: red, blue</div>';
            $prod_list_contents .= '<div class="span_product_name"><a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_PRODUCT_INFO, ($cPath ? 'cPath=' . $cPath . '&' : '') . 'products_id=' . $listing['products_id']) . '">' . $listing['products_name'] . '</div></a>';  


            $prod_list_contents .=  '<div class="span_price">CAD ' .$currencies->display_price($listing['products_price'], tep_get_tax_rate($listing['products_tax_class_id'])) .'</div>' ;  

            $prod_list_contents .= '</div></div>';
    }

    $prod_list_contents .= '    </div>' .
                           '  ' 
                          ;

    echo $prod_list_contents;
```

I am trying to incorporate a color table into the same div that is being displayed through this same variable. My color table is derived through the following bit of php:

```
<div >
<?php
     $ctr = 0;
     $clr=1;
       foreach($products_options_array as $products_options_array2) { 
       $ctr++;
       //if it is a color image, or a color hex
           if($products_options_array2['color_image']!='')
           {
            $clr_sec = "style=\"background-image:url(images/pattern/".$products_options_array2['color_image'].") !important; height:28px; width:28px;\"" . "class=\"testy\"";
           }
           else {
               $clr_sec = "style=\"background-color:".$products_options_array2['color_code']." !important; height:28px; width:28px;float:left;\"" . "class=\"testy\"";
               }
           ?>
         <div <?php echo $clr_sec;?>> </div>
        <?php 
        $clr++;
        } ?>
    </div>
```

I have tried adding it into the prod_list_contents variable but I don't think I can because of the php here is not METHODS. and requires semi colons etc. Is there another way to go about this? Or am I able to add it in and I'm just being stupid?

Comment: Use your PHP variables to store information about your products, but do NOT put all that HTML in one variable.  When you're retrieving values from the database, you can simply echo the HTML that you need.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly you wan to add $clr_sec to $prod_list_contents.

Just change

```
<div <?php echo $clr_sec;?>> </div>
```

to

```
 $prod_list_contents.='<div '.$clr_sec.'</div>';
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks. You do understand correctly. But because none of the for each loop is in there, I am only getting the last color in the $clr_sec variable echo'd

Comment: what? Just put the $prod_list_contents after the foreach loop.Also, try not to mix so much code with HTML it's really a bad practice

Comment: I tried just adding it in after the for each loop, however I think the for each loop is "finished" running by then and therefore $clr_sec reaches the final state. I also tried wrapping the while loop inside of the foreach loop to no success.